# Run code in a specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application which talks to an external library. Unfortunately all calls to the library must be made from the same thread.

How can I send method calls from one thread to another? (And, obviously, send the method results back to the calling thread.)

(No, this isn't to do with GUI programming. No, using the GUI message pump won't work.)

What I really want is for every single method on a particular class to always be executed in the same thread. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: In static constructor create a thread and keep it alive waiting. All jobs (calling public methods of class) are "queued" and then this thread will do them one by one and then wait again.

Comment: How do you expect that another thread to receive the "notifications"? I guess, it must be listening for them to arrive anyway - to check some incoming queue "manually". You've already mentioned that that's not like GUI programming, so you just don't have some win-form, which dispatches your callback on that thred, so you can not apply something like IncomingFunctionCall_OnArrived - you should still check on those notifications by your own.

Comment: Is your library bound to the thread you initialized it with (similar to a UI), or does it just require serialized access?

Comment: @Gusdor It requires all calls to happen in the thread it was initialised in. I don't need to worry about _concurrent_ threads trying to access it, I just need to make sure it happens in the correct thread.

Comment: Seems to me like you very much do need to worry about concurrent threads if the library blows up without them :D Does it provide a synchronization object handle?

Comment: @Gusdor Sadly the library provides no help at all. It merely assumes your code doesn't use threads. :-(

Comment: That's quite strange. Code that can only run on one thread is thread aware by definition - does it throw out errors if you use more threads?

Comment: @Gusdor It's an external C++ library. If I call it from a different thread, it simply blocks forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to do what Windows Forms and WPF do to set up their single threaded message pumps - inherit `SynchronizationContext`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your implementation, you will need to maintain a thread safe message queue, similar to this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56369/Thread-safe-priority-queue-in-C
Your message pump worker thread will constantly check for new delegates, and invoke them.

So why not just write a message pump?

Well, by inheriting `SynchronizationContext`, you get all the CLR goodies like `BackgroundWorker`, `AsyncOperationManager` and the new `await/async` pattern keyword for free! They will all magically join back to your library thread.

Here is some code for a *basic* message pump. It does *not* implement `SynchronizationContext`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace MessagePump
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessagePump p = new MessagePump();
            p.Start();
            p.AddMessage(() => Console.WriteLine("message 1"));
            p.AddMessage(() => Console.WriteLine("message 2"));
            p.AddMessage(() => Console.WriteLine("message 3"));

            Console.ReadLine();
            p.Stop();
        }
    }

    class MessagePump
    {
        bool m_Working = false;
        Queue<Action> m_Actions = new Queue<Action>();

        public void Start()
        {
            m_Working = true;
            Thread t = new Thread(DoPump);
            t.Name = "Message Pump Thread";
            t.Start();
        }
        void DoPump()
        {
            while (m_Working)
            {
                try
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(m_Actions);
                    while (m_Actions.Count > 0)
                    {
                        m_Actions.Dequeue()(); //dequeue and invoke a delegate
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(m_Actions);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100); //dont want to lock this core!
            }
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            m_Working = false;
        }

        public void AddMessage(Action act)
        {
            lock (m_Actions)
            {
                m_Actions.Enqueue(act);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Figuring out how to make a thread-safe queue is really the bit I'm having trouble with. Once you have that, it's just a matter of queueing up lambda functions representing the work you want done.